# Getting error when trying to change type DATE to DATETIME

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to change my column type date to datetime. 
However, Im getting an error:
syntax error at or near "DATETIME"

```
ALTER TABLE messages ALTER COLUMN date DATETIME;
```

I dont know why, im using PostgreSQL

Thanks!

Comment: Try `timestamp` instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff still getting same error but near Timestamp

Comment: 1. Don't use "date" as a column name.  You can get away with it, but it can cause a problem when using the data in some ways; 2. Use the word TYPE after the column name.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) there is no `datetime` type in Postgres.

To change the type of a column you need to use the `TYPE` keyword after the column's name [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE messages ALTER COLUMN "date" type timestamp;
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but you should avoid using keywords as column names.

Additionally "date" isn't a good name to begin with as it doesn't describe what kind of "date" that is. The "sent date"? The "receive date"? The "expiration date"?